# How to deal with .env file with Symfony 4

Tags: symfony, continuous-integration, environment-variables, symfony4

I am using `.env` file to store some information about environment (like DB details).

Symfony have a component https://github.com/MarcinOrlowski/process-dotenv to parse it, but I dont find how to generate it.

My project is "built" on GitlabCI that generate a ZIP file (as a release).

I have found https://github.com/MarcinOrlowski/process-dotenv project, but since Symfony dont propose this, I am wondering if it's a good practice or not?

Comment: I'm confused. Do you need to load the environment variables into gitlab ci or production?

Comment: I want to generate a release as a ZIP file, that include the .env file with prod db details.

Comment: Still not clear what you are asking for.  You typically don't want to store database credentials in a release.  Typically in production you don't even use the .env file.  Maybe this will help: https://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment.html#b-configure-your-environment-variables

Comment: That the problem with SF adoption :/ lot of developers have only a FTP access to deploy web site, that why I want to generate a .env where developer can complete if needed (like Wordpress / prestashop do with config.php file).

Comment: So maybe you are asking how to dynamically config the env variables?  I think you will need to fool around with the php putenv function in config.php.  Needless to say I don't use GitlabCI.  Good luck.